# Implementing Web Map Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, arcgis, wms

I want to create my own tiling service, to be displayed over a base map using ArcGIS silverlight map viewer, and found the best way to do so is to implement my own WMS.
I've looked around but things looks very vague to me. I've read that I have to implement the GetMap & GetCabapilities requests but not sure where and how. I want to use asp.net to host the service, can you guide me how to start with that 
Regards,

Comment: any comments on my suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing your own WMS is quite a challenge. Yes, it's true that the standard only demands that you implement GetMap and GetCapabilities, but the challenge is to do that well...

I would strongly recommend that you instead look at [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/) and [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome). They are both OpenSource and well documented, fairly easy to install and manage. They can work with lots of databases and deliver a lot of formats and reference systems.